# How to merge two JSON objects in vb.net?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

```
dt = getDetailsOfEmplyoeesMonth(getCurrentEmpId(), loc_id, day_type)
retVal = GetJSONString(dt)

dt = getPendingLeaveDetails(leave_id)
retVal1 = GetJSONString_reg(dt)

retVal = retVal +retVal1
```

This concatenating is not working!

Comment: please explain the "not working!"

Comment: "GetJSONString" function returns a string converted from datatable. Here, two tables should be merged into one. Second table rows should be appended in first table. then at last </table> should appear.

Comment: what is the error and what are you expecting. Plz explain as, question is incomplete...

Comment: "GetJSONString" function returns a string converted from datatable. Here, two tables should be merged into one. Second table rows should be appended in first table. then at last </table> should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `GetJSONString` try using merge on datatables like this:

```
dt = getDetailsOfEmplyoeesMonth(getCurrentEmpId(), loc_id, day_type)    
dt1 = getPendingLeaveDetails(leave_id)

dt.Merge(dt1);
```

Note: Column names of `DataTable` should be same

for further details [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I hope this might help you

Comment: i have used c# syntax, plz change according to vb.net :)

Comment: I can use it for current case. but its not a permanent solution.